# Why does this 3 line program return None as output?

Tags: python, list

I expect  b to become [1,2,3,4] why is it None?

```
a=[1,2,3]  
b=a.append(4)  
print b
```

Answer (score 1):

`list.append` add an item to a list and it **does not** return (IOW, return `None`).

If you want a new list with the new item added, use `+` instead:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = a + [4]
>>> print b
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `a.append(4)` doesn't return anything (it alters `a` in place). Try

```
a=[1,2,3]
a.append(4)
b = a
print b
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, you didn't define *b*, it's a method of lists that return *none*.

```
>>> a=[1,2,3]
>>> b=a.append(4)
>>> print (b)
None
>>> type(b)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>>
```

Returning nothing.